# Is there a way to have a "universal variable" in Java Web?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Is there a way to have a variable that affects all sessions and all users in Java Web, Java Servlets and JSP?

I know you can have these variables in the database but is there an other way to achive this?

Comment: There are three scopes you might use; request, *page* or *application*.

Comment: I mean one that can be accesed from any session and client, you know, each time one user logs into my web app they create a new session that is sepparate from the other ones and has no communication with them unless they communicate throught the database.

Comment: Read my comment again, since your question *explicitly* asks for ways beside the database.

Comment: can you explain the three of them? Is just that we have data we need to store on the application but we can neither have an external document (I mean .json for example) nor store it in the database, but we can store it as a variable that can be accesible to all the application. Also, this is a variable so it changes over time.

Comment: Then you could store it in the application scope. For a full explanation I suggest you read Head First Servlets and JSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think servlet context will do the job.

For example:

ServletContextListener

```
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        arg0.getServletContext().setAttribute("my_var", 0);
        ...
}
```

HttpServlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int myVar = (Integer) getServletContext().getAttribute("my_var");
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare public class then add static variables.

```
public class Globals {
   public static int globalVariable = 0;
}
```

then `Globals.globalVariable` will be accessible anywhere within application.

Comment: But this would change each time a new user logs in, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in many ways:

- Use a config file

  Maybe you can use config file, for example, there is a config.properties, which has `level = 10`, you load it in a Listener when web server start, and store in memory via a Map, and you can change/access it any time, you can send the value via json to front-end too.
- Use Application scope variable in jsp/servlet

Comment: ServletContext (Application scope variable) is a good option.

Comment: @arturojain Yes, that's the best for jsp/servlet application. But if you want to make it programming language independent, e.g. provide API to php, you might like config file based approch.